# How to automaticaly power off hdd

Tags: hard-drive, suspend, hdparm

I have laptop with two hard drives. First is SSD (with system) and the second is HDD with my private files. So I would like to setup to automatically power off of disk after 4 minutes. I set hdparm -S 48. It didn't work. So I set hdparm -B. If I set value 64 and lower the hard drive will be power off in few second. If I set value 65 and higher, the hard drive will never shut down...

Please, does anyone know, how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Some hard drives do not respond to `hdparm` the same was as others, which can make this difficult. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) the brand and model of your hard drive (2) the Terminal output of `sudo hdparm -B /dev/sdb` (be sure to replace `sdb` with the actual device name for your hard drive). With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 